# Graphic design program not working

Tags: php

I recently read about graphic design extensions in PHP and I am trying to create a square with different colors. [Example](http://www.stefstudio.com/photos/b_0131.jpg).

Here is my program:

```
<?php
$color = array(0 => array('35', '3B', '1A'),
               1 => array('7E', 'A6', '29'),
               2 => array('D9', 'C9', '9A'),
               3 => array('D9', '30', '30'),
               4 => array('73', '07', '10'),
               5 => array('D9', '62', 'C6')
               );
$image = imagecreate(200,200);
$maxsize = 200;
$currentcolor = 0;
$yellow = imagecolorallocate($image, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00);
for($i = 0; $i <= 200; $i += 10) {
    if($currentcolor == 6) {
        $currentcolor = 0;
    }
    $red = "0x".$color[$currentcolor][0];
    $green = "0x".$color[$currentcolor][1];
    $blue = "0x".$color[$currentcolor][2];
    $red = (int)$red;
    $green = (int)$green;
    $blue = (int)$blue;
    $rescolor = imagecolorallocate($image, $red, $green, $blue);
    imagefilledrectangle($image, $i, $i, $maxsize -= 10, $maxsize -= 10, $rescolor);
    $currentcolor++;
}
header("Content-Type: image/png");
imagepng($image);
?>
```

However, this code produces only a black square. How can I make the square multicolored?

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: What is your question? What are the current results of your existing code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you describe what you are attempting, what result you expect, and what is happening _instead_ of your intended result? Include any error messages you receive.

Comment: i Just got Black Square not  multicolor square.i dont know why.Thats my problem

Comment: Read the comments below imagecolorallocate(): "If you even in a situation where it's not allocating the color you want it could be because of your images color allocation table. GIF and 8-bit PNG images are very susceptible to this." http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocate.php

Comment: this line looks problematic `$currentco'enter code here'lor++;`

Answer (score 0):

These two arguments are almost CERTAINLY not what you want:

```
imagefilledrectangle($image, $i, $i, $maxsize -= 10, $maxsize -= 10, $rescolor);'
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This code is actually functioning as:

```
$maxsize = $maxsize - 10;
$foo = $maxsize;
$maxsize = $maxsize - 10;
$bar = $maxsize;
imagefilledrectangle($image, $i, $i, $foo, $bar, $rescolor);
```